# How to generate an Rmarkdown file from a function

Tags: r, r-markdown

if anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.

I would like to create a function that returns a list with some files, such as dataframes and plots, from the parameters specified in the function.

I would also like this function to generate an Rmarkdown file, in which the tables and plots generated in the function would be displayed. This could perhaps be done with `rmarkdown::render()` inside the function, but I'm not sure how exactly.

The function would be something like:

```
# dataset:
data=data.frame(value=rnorm(100))


myfunction <- function(data, color){
  
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram(color = color)

data2 <- data$col2 <- 1:100

mylist <- list(plot = p, data = data2)
return(mylist)

}

test <- myfunction(data, "red")
```

The idea is that the function generates the Rmarkdown file in a folder on the computer, and the user is free to specify the parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is "yes" you can. Here is one potential solution:

```
library(ggplot2)

# dataset:
data=data.frame(value=rnorm(100))


myfunction <- function(data, color){
  
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=value)) + 
    geom_histogram(color = color)
  
  cat("---
title: \"example Rmd\"
author: \"Jared_Mamrot\"
date: \'2022-06-06\'
output: html_document
---
  
\`\`\`{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
\`\`\`

## Example plot
\`\`\`{r example, echo=TRUE}
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram(color = color)
p
\`\`\`", 
file = "tmp.Rmd")
  rmarkdown::render("tmp.Rmd")
  data2 <- data$col2 <- 1:100
  
  mylist <- list(plot = p, data = data2)
  return(mylist)
  
}

test <- myfunction(data, "red")
```

Output ("tmp.html"):

```
example Rmd
Jared_Mamrot
2022-06-06
Example plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram(color = color)
p
## `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with
## `binwidth`.
```

[image: example.png]

```
test2 <- myfunction(data, "deepskyblue")
```

Output ("tmp.html"):

```
example Rmd
Jared_Mamrot
2022-06-06
Example plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram(color = color)
p
## `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with
## `binwidth`.
```

[image: example_2.png]

Comment: Thank you Jared! Can I render without writing inside `cat()`? I wanted to have a Rmarkdown model ready, and just change the parameters in the function. Do you know if this is possible too?

Comment: I don't need to write inside "cat", so I used my Rmarkdown template in `rmarkdown::render("mytemplate.Rmd")` and it worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This takes the output of myfunction and renders it as html or pdf using knitr::spin.  If the output is called test then it creates a file called test.R which it spins into test.md and then renders it as test.html (test.pdf if pdf_document() had been specified).  All files are in the current directory. Note that this separates the generation of the list and generation of the html or pdf output for modularity.

```
library(gglot2)
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

# inputs are a named list of R objects and optional output type
spin_list <- function(List, output_format = html_document()) {
  stem <- deparse(substitute(List))
  Rfile <- paste0(stem, ".R")
  cat("#' ---\n#' title: \"", stem, "\"\n#' ---\n", file = Rfile, sep = "")
  for(nm in names(List)) {
    s <- sprintf("\n#+ %s, echo=FALSE\nprint(List[['%s']])\n", nm, nm)
    cat(s, file = Rfile, append = TRUE)
  }
  spin(Rfile)
  md <- paste0(stem, ".md")
  render(md, output_format)
}

spin_list(test) # test is created in question
browseURL("test.html")
```

The generated test.R is:

```
#' ---
#' title: "test"
#' ---

#+ plot, echo=FALSE
print(List[['plot']])

#+ data, echo=FALSE
print(List[['data']])
```